# .NET CMS for creating a new website

Tags: .net, content-management-system

Can someone recommend a CMS to me? I need to create a website. My website will provide the following functionality:

- Blogs
- Discussion forums
- Picture gallery
- Multi-lingual

My skill set is MS .NET, so the language of choice is C# (or VB). I understand that I can code all the above requirements, but it will take me forever -- I am the only developer. So I'm trying to find a CMS that would help me to build the website. The CMS should be:

- Free
- Support .NET as the programming platform
- Support as many of my features as possible

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Umbraco.com](http://umbraco.com) which is open-source and, what I know, widely used.

Good luck!